# PHP Regex to match words outside oh [URL] and [IMG] BBCode?

Tags: php, regex, forum, bbcode

hoping someone can help me. I am making a PHP plugin for my forum. The goal is whenever someone types the word Amazon in a post it will automatically turn it into a link to Amazon.

I need to edit the text as it is saved in the database, before it has been converted to HTML and is still in BBCode format.

Example Text:

I really like shopping at Amazon. Here is a link: [URL="http:www.amazon.com"]Link to Amazon[URL] and here is an image: [img]http://images.amazon.com/amazon/image/zzz.jpg[/img]. Here is one more simple link: [url]http://www.amazon.net[/url]. Remember, Amazon is awesome!

--

In the above example only the very first and very last instance of "Amazon" should be matched, all the others need to be ignored.

I tried to alter a regex that does something similar except in HTML tags but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Sure- I started with the following that I was using for doing the same edits in HTML-

Comment: Sure- I started with the following that I was using for doing the same edits in HTML- 

`Amazon(?![^<]*(</a>|" />|width="\d+"|target="_blank"|follow">|rel="thickbox">|onclick="[\w .()]+"))`

which I realize is a little complicated but it actually worked great since the HTML being used is always consistent.

So I broke it down to just the part that keeps it out of HTML tags

`Amazon(?![^<]*(</a>|" />))`

I tried changing it around

`Amazon(?![^\[]*(\[/url]|"]))`

Comment: which is actually pretty decent then I added in something to stop if from working in [img]

`Amazon(?![^\[]*(\[/url]|"]|\[/img]))`

Which seems to work... So now I don't know why it didn't work for me yesterday. Maybe I answered my own question! :)

Comment: If you found it yourself, perfect! Persistence works, sometimes! :) Don't forget to add the answer yourself and mark the question as answered so others can refer to it, it could be a handy snippet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working it out, this seems to work-

```
Amazon(?![^\[]*(\[/url]|"]|\[/img]))
```

This will skip Amazon in any URL tag (long or short) and all IMG tags.